# Abort redux AsyncThunk in different scopes (Redux toolkit)

Tags: react-native

In all examples ive seen online and in the documentation of RTK itself, i've seen that people abort it in the same scope,

```js
import { fetchUserById } from './slice'
import { useAppDispatch } from './store'
import React from 'react'

function MyComponent(props) {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Dispatching the thunk returns a promise
    const promise = dispatch(fetchUserById(props.userId))
    return () => {
      // `createAsyncThunk` attaches an `abort()` method to the promise
      promise.abort()
    }
  }, [props.userId])
}
```

what if i want to abort the promise in **different** scopes:

**usage case:**
Search button gets data from a slow api, i launch the search there with

```js
dispatch(placesFetchData({
  lattitude: location.coords.latitude,
  longitude: location.coords.longitude,
}));
```

user clicks on another "tab" (ie navigates to another component)

we run promise.abort()
both in a useEffect, return scope (ie component unmount)

or user clicks on "cancel search"

Should i store the promise in a useState so i can access it throughout my component? it feels a bit janky to do that, what do you guys propose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved it with useRef()

const abortSearch = useRef();

abortSearch.current = dispatchPromise.abort;

i can use this anywhere in my component to cancel the promise

abortSearch.current("cancel reason");

Comment: can you please share a code snipped? I don't get 100% how you solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using a controller that is accessible as a singleton throughout my application. It is in a .ts file instead of a tsx file, and outside of the react component lifecycle, so I am not depending on any React Hooks.

I have a private property in the controller:

`private abort: ((reason: string | undefined) => void) | undefined;`

When I dispatch the action, I then run:

`this.setAbort(action.abort);` *where setAbort() is a basic setter*

and then when I need to abort, I go:

`if (this.abort) this.abort("Aborting");`